# Zeppelin with spark 1.5.2 on mapr - failed dependency

Tags: apache-spark, mapr, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to install Apache Zeppelin on Mapr5 (spark 1.5.2 hadoop 2.7.0). I followed instructions from this page https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin

When I used the following command

> mvn -Pmapr50 -Pyarn -Pbuild-distr -Pspark-1.5 -Dspark.version=1.5.2
>   -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.0 -Ppyspark package -DskipTests -B

I get the following error,

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project zeppelin-spark-dependencies:
>   Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-spark-dependencies:jar:0.5.6-incubating:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at
>   org.apache.spark:spark-repl_2.10:jar:1.5.2 ->
>   org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.5.2 ->
>   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.7.0-mapr-1509 ->
>   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.0-mapr-1509 ->
>   com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.0.9-mapr: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.0.9-mapr: Could not
>   transfer artifact com.mapr:mapr-root:pom:2.0-SNAPSHOT from/to
>   apache.snapshots.https (${env.MAPR_MAVEN_REPO}): Cannot access
>   ${env.MAPR_MAVEN_REPO} with type default using the available connector
>   factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access
>   ${env.MAPR_MAVEN_REPO} using the registered transporter factories:
>   WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported transport protocol -> [Help 1]

Irrespective of the Zeppelin version, I get the same error as above. But I don't get this error when I use spark version as 1.4 in the mvn command. Can someone help me to get out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but it was resolved by setting the following environment variable.

```
export MAPR_MAVEN_REPO=http://repository.mapr.com/maven
```